# How is morale resolved when the Bonding Knife and Tormentor rules are in effect?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I recently ran into an issue where two different rules conflicted without an obvious intended solution.

- Tau have their Bonding Knife Ritual rule: "If you roll a 6 when taking a Morale test for this unit, the test is automatically passed."
- Likewise, the Drukhari Incubi have the Tormentor rule: "When a Morale test is taken for an enemy unit within 6" of any INCUBI units from your army, and the result of that Morale test is equal to the highest Leadership characteristic in that enemy unit, the test is failed and one model flees that enemy unit."

In our situation, a unit with Leadership 7 lost 1 model and rolled a 6 for their morale test. In this event when both conditions are triggered, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With the release of 9th edition, the new core rule book contains a "Rare Rules" item that addresses the situation above

**Morale Priority:** If a unit is affected by conflicting rules, those that automatically pass Morale tests or cause no models to flee take precedence.

With that rule in place, Bonding Knife Ritual takes precedence and the test will be passed.